# Crypto standards

Tags: pgp, standards

According to [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/755655) and status of PGP on [RFC search](https://www.rfc-editor.org/search/rfc_search.php), OpenPGP RFCs can be used as "technical reference for the applicable internet standard". The quote mentioned in previous sentence is a little vague. In Crypto community, is OpenPGP widely accepted as a standard? Would anyone know what is holding OpenPGP's status to be changed from Proposed Standard to Internet Standard? Even though the pointed [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/755655) seems to suggest that it is just a matter of lingo, and for practical purposes it is a standard. Is OpenPGP recognized by any other standards body as a standard?

Comment: There's mention on OpenPGP in [IEC TS 62325-502](https://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_iec62325-502%7Bed1.0%7Den.pdf). Some relevant queries: https://www.google.com/search?q=openPGP+site%3Aiso.org and https://www.google.com/search?q=openPGP+site%3Aetsi.org

Comment: Have a look at [RFC 7127](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7127#section-2). The OpenPGP Message Format is specified in [RFC 4880](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4880) as a 'Proposed Standard'. Many Proposed Standards are widely used on the Internet as stable protocols. For example, TLS 1.3 is [also](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc8446) a Proposed Standard. I don't think most people care what is and isn't officially a standard as long as the thing is standardised (set in stone and properly specified).